# Get all checked items and delete them using button_to

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table with some data and there is also a checbox in each table row and each of them has an unique id like '`chk_1`'. There is a button `delete`.

```
= button_to 'delete', {controller: 'users', id: '1'}, method: :delete
```

where `id: '1'` is just a stub. I want the button to delete all checked items. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't a way to do this in the RESTful way in which you are attempting to so.

I would just build a form (`<%= form_tag("/users/delete_users", :method => "delete") %>`) and submit it to your Users controller and write some code in that method to delete the check items.

Your checked items will be available in the `params` hash, and you can delete them all using something like this, assuming all checkboxes have the same "name" and the value of the checkboxes are the user's Id.

```
def delete_users
  users_to_delete = params[:users_to_delete]
  users_to_delete.each{ |user_id| User.find(user_id).destroy }
end
```

Comment: but I have many different buttons: for deleting, for activating.... How do I combine all these 'form_tag'? I mean, checkboxes in the main table should be placed inside form tag.

Comment: what does the view code look like for your `activate` action?

Comment: I can't help you if I can't see what you are trying to do.